# Pocket-Planes Strategies

Tags: ios, pocket-planes

I wanted to know if thier was a specific strategy for playing pocket planes. So far I started in Montreal and Skipped along poor airports on the east coast down into South America, and then crossed over the ocean into Monrovia and up to Manchester.......

I guess I want to know if I should have focused on one area completely before jumping around continents.

Answer (score 3):

Aiming for maximum distances is not the best strategy for profitability. If you do the math, you'll see that the shortest distances yield the highest profit per minute than the longer ones do. While it may take more short flights to make the same profit as a much longer flight, you can do it in much less time, making short flights more profitable. Once you're done for the day, then you can send all your planes on a long trip so that you'll have a nice gain when you pick up the game again.

To do the test, fill up a plane with passengers/cargo for a long trip, and then take your profit and divide it by the minutes for the flight. Then do the same for a very short flight. You will see that the short flight has a much higher profit per minute than the long flight.

Answer (score 0):

You want to aim for maximum distances for deliveries as well as getting the "one plane full of same destination" bonus.  You could (although I haven't tried this yet) set up a couple of "hub" class 2 cities - Toronto and Atlanta, let's say.  Then open up some class 1 airports near each of them - Ottawa and Quebec and then Orlando and Havana.  Then use your class 2 large planes as loss leaders to aggregate a bunch of items going north (or south).  Then use class 1 planes to get a full load going to Orlando (laid-over in Atlanta) and get the huge bonus because these items came all the way from Quebec.  Remember, time is irrelevant to the items, just distance, so they can stay in layover as long as you need to get that full-plane bonus.